# WorkManager listen to chained tasks

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I see we can check each Worker by using below code:

```
WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(compressionWork.id)
            .observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer { workInfo ->
                // Do something with the status
                if (workInfo != null && workInfo.state.isFinished) {
                    // ...
                }
            })
```

But i don't know how to check if chained tasks is complete or not. Anyway to check it? Thanks.